# Remove code blocks in Markdown file using SED command

Tags: linux, unix, sed, markdown

I have article which is a markdown document ( `*.md` ) file. It has code fences as below

````
```
My code fence
```
````

I am using an automated spell checker tool to check the spelling in my document called by a script. Is it possible to remove the code fence block , before i give the input the spell check tool. Is it possible using ***SED*** command in Unix.

Request the help of all veterans.

Editing for more clarity. Below is my script:

````
#!/bin/bash
TEXT_CONTENT=`cat $(echo python_tips.md | sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g')`
TEXT_CONTENT=`echo "$TEXT_CONTENT" | sed -E 's/\{:([^\}]+)\}//g'`
TEXT_CONTENT=`echo "$TEXT_CONTENT" | sed -E 's/<([^<]+)>//g'`
TEXT_CONTENT=`echo "$TEXT_CONTENT" | sed -E 's/http(s)?:\/\/([^ ]+)//g'`
TEXT_CONTENT=`echo "$TEXT_CONTENT" | sed  -n '/```/,/```/ !p'`
echo $TEXT_CONTENT
````

I get the below error when running the command:

```
./new_script.sh: command substitution: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./new_script.sh: command substitution: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
./new_script.sh: command substitution: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./new_script.sh: command substitution: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: 1) use `$(...)` syntax for command substitution, backticks are obsolete. 2) `echo python_tips.md` doesn't output `python_tips.md`'s contents, `cat python_tips.md` does that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input:**

````
$ cat input.md
Indent every line of the block by at least 4 spaces.

This is a normal paragraph:

    This is a code block.
    With multiple lines.

Alternatively, you can use 3 backtick quote marks ``` before and after the block, like this:

```
This is a code block
```

however, this ``` sample ``` is not a code block.

To add syntax highlighting to a code block, add the name of the language immediately
after the backticks: 

```javascript
var oldUnload = window.onbeforeunload;
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    saveCoverage();
    if (oldUnload) {
        return oldUnload.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```
````

**CMD:**

````
sed '/^```/,/^```/d' input.md
````

**Output:**

````
$ sed '/^```/,/^```/d' input.md
Indent every line of the block by at least 4 spaces.

This is a normal paragraph:

    This is a code block.
    With multiple lines.

Alternatively, you can use 3 backtick quote marks ``` before and after the block, like this:


however, this ``` sample ``` is not a code block.

To add syntax highlighting to a code block, add the name of the language immediately
after the backticks:
````

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible using an address range and **d**elete command.

````
sed '/```/,//d' file
````

Comment: Thanks @oguz ismail

Comment: @Sunil you're welcome. A sidenote: you can shorten the sed command Allan has given in his answer like this `sed '/^```/,//d' file`.

Comment: what does the below command do?

**sed  -n '/```/,/```/ !p'**

Comment: Below is my shell script
`
#!/bin/bash
TEXT_CONTENT=`cat $(echo python_tips.md | sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g')`
TEXT_CONTENT=`echo "$TEXT_CONTENT" | sed -E 's/http(s)?:\/\/([^ ]+)//g'`
TEXT_CONTENT=`echo "$TEXT_CONTENT" | sed  -n '/```/,/```/ !p'`
`
am getting error while executing
`
./new_script.sh: command substitution: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./new_script.sh: command substitution: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

`
Any help?

Comment: @Sunil don't paste code here in comments. Add it to your question